# Cursor and content doesn't update when using Yjs et Sandpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webrtc, codemirror

I'm using Yjs and Sandpack to build a simple Collaborative code editor.
I doesn't receive any error on console and I see other people cursor but when I update content, nothing happen on the other side. the curosor doesn't seems to update.

```
import * as Y from "yjs";
import { yCollab } from "y-codemirror.next";
import { WebrtcProvider } from "y-webrtc";

const ydoc = new Y.Doc();
const provider = new WebrtcProvider("codemirror6-demo-room", ydoc, {
  signaling: ["ws://localhost:4444"]
});
const ytext = ydoc.getText("codemirror");
const undoManager = new Y.UndoManager(ytext);

export default function Code({ template, theme, language, roomId = "pipi" }: ICode) {
  const codemirrorInstance = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cmInstance = codemirrorInstance.current?.getCodemirror();
    
    if (!cmInstance) return;

    const txt = cmInstance.state.update({
      doc: ytext.toString()
    });

    cmInstance.update([txt]);

    return () => {
      provider.disconnect();
      provider.destroy();
    };
  },[]);

  return (
    <SandpackProvider template={template} theme={theme}>
      <SandpackLayout>
        <SandpackFileExplorer />
        <SandpackCodeEditor
          ref={codemirrorInstance}
          showTabs
          showLineNumbers
          showInlineErrors
          wrapContent
          closableTabs
          extensions={[yCollab(ytext, provider.awareness, { undoManager })]}
        />
        <SandpackPreview
          showNavigator={true}
          showRefreshButton={true}
          showOpenInCodeSandbox={false}
          showOpenNewtab={true}
          showRestartButton={true}
        />
      </SandpackLayout>
    </SandpackProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you start the server side  weboskcet service? https://github.com/yjs/y-websocket